# add 2 inline styles to child elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Id like to add an inline style based on a click:

**css:**

```
div#ProductImages > img
{
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

div#ProductImages > img:hover
{
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

So when they click on one of the child image icons the opacity is 1.0

This what i have tried:

```
$("div#ProductImages > img").click('style', 'opacity: 1.0', 'filter:alpha(opacity=100)');
```

which doesnt seem to work?

Comment: Well, that's not how `.click` works at all.  I wonder why you even tried this. Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/click/.  Regarding animation, you probably want to use http://api.jquery.com/animate/. But the CSS rules will work, even without jQuery (not in IE6 though).

Comment: Inline styles are the devil. Css is lovely. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div#ProductImages > img").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('newClassName'); 
});
```

and **css** is:

```
.newClassName{
   opacity:1.0;
   filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#ProductImages > img").click( function() {
    $(this).css('opacity' , '1.0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this:

```
$("div#ProductImages > img").click(function(){
    $(this).css({'opacity':'1.0'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, it's probably best to use a class, with the required attributes and then add / remove it when necessary. It's also worth noting that in your question, the CSS refers to `hover`, but the JavaScript refers to `click`. For this demonstration, I'm going to use `hover` to offer better exposure to event handler in jQuery.

### Css

```
div#ProductImages > img
{
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}

div#ProductImages > img:hover,
div#ProductImages > img.onHover
{
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

### JavaScript (using jQuery)

```
$('div#ProductImages > img').hover(function()
{
    $(this).addClass('onHover');
}, function()
{
    $(this).removeClass('onHover');
});
```